# Compact password-protected Access 2010 database using command-line

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 data base that I want to compact with a batch file via command-line, the code I use is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"  
     "\\database_rute\database.mdb" /pwd="xxxx" /compact
```

When I open the .bat file, it opens the data base but it keeps asking me the password.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the password without the quotes.  (Batch files run in the command interpreter not MS DOS which has not existed as part of windows for a long long time).

Comment: It doesn't work, access is open but ask me the username and the password to log in

Comment: remove the `=` from `pwd=`  if that does not fix it add add `/user username`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Access-558cfe1d-3c98-4292-bee8-1f5df9702bf1) link, the `/pwd` command line switch:

> Applies to Access 2002-2003 and earlier databases only.

I am looking for an answer to the same question but haven't found one yet. I need to compact/repair several password-protected databases via the command line.